# Is it possible to create an Annotation on a variable that listens for changes?

Tags: java, callback, annotations

I have some code that looks like:

```
public class Custom {

    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 0;

    public void doSomething() { ... }

    public void setA(int a) { this.a = a; doSomething(); }

    public void setB(int b) { this.b = b; doSomething(); }

}
```

This pattern is quite common for me and happens in a few of my classes. Is there any way to use Java's annotation system to create something like:

```
public class Custom {

    @Callback(method=doSomething)
    private int a = 0;

    @Callback(method=doSomething)
    private int b = 0;

    private void doSomething() { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Annotation itself does nothing. It can just mark the field, method, class etc. This mark can be used by other code that implements some actions.

In your case you can either use dynamic proxy or byte code engineering technique, for example AspectJ.

Comment: Thanks - I, depressingly, accept this answer. It's funny how a language can make an easy task impossible.